# How to get angles from given position in $3D$?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, 3d, rotations, angle

I am struggling with a problem in the $3D$ coordinate system.
I have a point given by its coordinates (I also know the distance from the origin, so I don't have to bother with counting that) and I need to make a line segment from the origin to this point by rotating the line segment. 
**How can I get angles to rotate it?**

I suppose I need only two angles. I was trying to use some arctangent formula, but I am not able to finish it.

The best I could do was

> $angle_1 = \arctan(\frac{x}{diag_{xy}})$; $angle_2 = \arctan(\frac{y}{x})$

but that doesn't work.

Comment: Try googling "spherical coordinates". Those are usually given as one angle from the $xz$-plane, add the angle from the $z$-axis.

Comment: Let A be the given point. You don't say if you want to rotate segment OA around one of the axes , e.g., the $z$ axis, or around another axis OB ?

Comment: I need all the rotations around the three basic axis.

Comment: When you answer to somebody that is not either the OP, or somebody who has provided an answer, please begin by arobas followed by its pseudo. Otherwise, no alert will reach him/her.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was given this advice (originally from: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Transformations#rotate):

$length = $norm$([x,y,z])$;  // radial distance

$b = \arccos(\frac{z}{length})$; // inclination angle

$c = atan2(y,x)$;     // azimuthal angle

the b and c is actually the angles I was looking for.

x,y,z are coordinates of given point.

where norm() is euclidian norm of vector https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Mathematical_Functions#norm.

And atan2 is the arctangent function with two arguments https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ be the coordinates of point $A.$

Using a +45° rotation around $x$ axis gives point A_1 with the following coordinates:

$$\begin{cases}x_1&=&x_0\\y_1&=&y_0 \cos(45°) - z_0 \sin(45°)\\z_1&=&y_0 \sin(45°) + z_0 \cos(45°)\end{cases}$$

then the +45° rotation around $z$ axis of point $A_1$ gives point $A_2$:

$$\begin{cases}x_2&=&x_1 \cos(45°) - y_1 \sin(45°)\\y_2&=&x_1 \sin(45°) + y_1 \cos(45°)\\z_2&=&z_1\end{cases}.$$

Remark: $\cos(45°)=\sin(45°)=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand that. Where can I find the angles I need? Or maybe, how does this join works?

Comment: There is a misunderstanding between us. Do you mean that you have an initial position $A$ and that you have a final position $B$, (imperatively with $OA=OB$) that you want to reach B starting from $A$ by three consecutive rotations around axes $x$, $y$ and then $z$ ?

Comment: I am not sure now. I have a point A and line segment (at the beginning it is pointing to direction 1,0,0) and I need to rotate it so it become as you say OA. But i need angles due to the axis.

Comment: Can this movement be described on a (fictitious) sphere centered in $O$ with radius $OA$ ?

Comment: If i correctly understand then yes.

Comment: Example: A coordinates=[1,1,1], I need angles 45,0 and 45

Comment: Do you mean, on a fictitious sphere of radius $\sqrt{3}$ on which ^$A$ is sitituated, make a rotation with 45° angle around $x$ axis, then a rotation with 45° angle around $z$ axis ?

Comment: I don't see the point of this sphere (but I believe you, that it has one), but yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: Then I turn my answer in this direction :)

Comment: Done: I have completely modified my former answer. I wish it is convenient for you.

Comment: I am sorry, but that is still something else :). The 45° was just an example. And I do not need the new points coordinates but the angles of rotation. Would it somehow work with your equations? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I come back only now (just a little after Xmas midnight CET). Do we agree that for example, we have two points like $A(1,1,1)$ and $B(1,0,\sqrt{2})$ that are at the same distance of the origin $\sqrt{1^2+1^2+1^2}=\sqrt{1^2+0^2+\sqrt{2}^2}=\sqrt{3}$ and you want to know the angles of rotation around $x$,$y$,and $z$ that brings $A$ finally to $B$ ?

Comment: I think so. I posted the answer that is suitable (so I do not need this anymore) but it has some "nasty" functions, so maybe someone would use some simpler solution.